# how to find all spec/test files related to a model/controller in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I have been trying to think a way I can find all the test which uses a specific model but couldn't do it. I have approx 13000 tests written in the application and while modifying the code I am unaware which tests will fail because of the changes.

Language/Framework: Ruby on Rails

eg:

Model A.rb:

def update
some code
end

test/spec A:
uses Model A

test/spec B:
uses Model A

List of tests using Model A:

1. test/spec A:
2. test/spec B:

Comment: That depends entirely on your application. On the one hand, you can write only unit tests that only test one specific model and all external dependencies are mocked or stubbed. On the other hand, your test could be mainly integration tests, testing multiple models at once.

Comment: Perhaps you can try [crystalball](https://github.com/toptal/crystalball). It runs a subset of your test suite to see if anything changed. Although you will need to run all the specs to ensure if everything is ok

Comment: "and while modifying the code I am unaware which tests will fail because of the changes."  - the only way to get a 100% sure answer to that question is to run the entire test suite. If you're using guard for example its default watchers make some simple assumptions based on what you're changing and for example runs `spec/models/*_spec.rb` when you change a file in `app/models`. Thats good enough for instant feedback but you still need to run the whole test suite before commiting or merging your branch (depending on your workflow).

Comment: The code quality of the application itself is going to play a huge role in the question if you can actually run subsets of your tests and get decent feedback. The more tightly coupled the code is the more (undesired) side effects any change will have and the more failures you will have when you run the rest of the tests.